# Could not cast value of type UIViewController to RecordDrawerController

Tags: swift, xcode8

I've duplicated a target and it's schema and I'm trying to run the project but it fails for any reason I don't know.

Here bellow I paste a capture of the error.

[image]

Any help with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could not cast value of type UIViewController to
>   RecordDrawerController

Select the top yellow button of the appropriate view controller, then Goto `Utilities -> Identity Inspector -> Custom Class -> Class` and then change appropriate view controller custom class as `RecordDrawerController` on story board.

[image]

Comment: @DevStarlight , You are welcome :) let me know, is it worked for you?

Comment: Finally the class was fine but there was a static module, so it wasn't working! but you gave me the key! Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes. I missed that.